# How do I add a video instead of a photo on top wrapper?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I would like to use a video on my top wrapper place instead of using a photo as background img.
I am really beginner of html5 & css3, so I am really sorry if my question isn't clear.

That would be really appreciate if someone could teach me how I can code to add a background video not as full screen type background, only for my top wrapper.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>TakashiKaida</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="header-left">
        </div>
        <div class="header-right">
          <a href="file:///Users/takashikaida/Documents/Takashi%20Kaida%20Personal/index.html">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="about">About</a>
          <a href="#" class="blog">Blog</a>
          <a href="#" class="cv">CV</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="top-wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>HELLO, IT'S ME.</h1>
        <h1>I AM TAKASHI</h1>
        <p><br><br>Marketing Analyst/Assistant</p>
        <p>Co-Founder and CEO of <a href="file:///Users/takashikaida/Desktop/Flow%20Full%20Screen%20Type/index.html" target="_blank"> <strong>FLOW</strong></a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN";
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  width: 1170px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.top-wrapper {
  padding: 180px 0 100px 0;
  background-image: url(background-photo.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.top-wrapper h1 {
  font-size: 75px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.top-wrapper p {
  font-size: 25px;
}

header {
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(34, 49, 52, 0.9);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}


.logo {
  width: 124px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.header-left {
  float: left;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}


.header-right a {
  line-height: 65px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

.about-me {
  height: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  text-align: center;
}

.heading {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  color: #5f5d60;
}

.heading h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.profile {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.lesson-icon {
  position: relative;
}

.lesson-icon p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.txt-contents {
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #b3aeb5;
}

.heading h3 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.message-wrapper {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

.message {
  padding: 15px 40px;
  background-color: #5dca88;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 7px #1a7940;
}

.message:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 7px;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.bottom-btn-list {
  text-align: center;
}


footer p {
  color: #b3aeb5;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}


footer {
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333631
}

.my-skyblue {
  color: skyblue;
}

.my-white {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: use a `video` tag with appropriate styling to put it in the background

Comment: additional hint for @JaromandaX comment: `<video>` & `.container` should have `position absolute;` and `.top-wrapper` `position: relative;`

Comment: @davbuc - that's what I said ... *appropriate styling* :D - though the only thing left to consider is getting the video element sizing to follow the container

Comment: @davbuc - don't make the container absolute, just the video absolute, and the top-wrapper relative, then make the video 100% width and height and it will take the dimensions of the container since now top-wrapper will be the size of container only

Comment: .container {
  width: 1170px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.top-wrapper {
position:relative;
}


.top-wrapper video {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:green;
z-index:-1;
}

Comment: video width doesn't extend till edge ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple. You can add video from following methods.

1. `<video src="/myvideo.mp4"></video>`
2. `<video src="video.mp4" controls> <object data="player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"> <param value="player.swf" name="movie"/> ...etc... </object> </video>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thought, you can try that:

1. you can use `video` tag to import your video file
2. set style of `video`, like:

```
video {
 min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
 width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
}
```

Comment: your style would make it fixed behind the whole page - did you read the question?

Comment: @JaromandaX Thats not important, if u dont want to be fixed, just change style, float flex its all ok

Answer (score 0):

Add a video element inside top-wrapper, see the styling below

```css
.top-wrapper {
position:relative;
background:rgba(255,0,0,0.1);
}
.top-wrapper .video {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:green;
z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>TakashiKaida</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="header-left">
        </div>
        <div class="header-right">
          <a href="file:///Users/takashikaida/Documents/Takashi%20Kaida%20Personal/index.html">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="about">About</a>
          <a href="#" class="blog">Blog</a>
          <a href="#" class="cv">CV</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="top-wrapper">
      <video class="video" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fc/Storforsen_video_12.webm" autoplay></video>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>HELLO, IT'S ME.</h1>
        <h1>I AM TAKASHI</h1>
        <p><br><br>Marketing Analyst/Assistant</p>
        <p>Co-Founder and CEO of <a href="file:///Users/takashikaida/Desktop/Flow%20Full%20Screen%20Type/index.html" target="_blank"> <strong>FLOW</strong></a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I just replaced the video url to mine, but video isn't come out...i really don't know why...

Comment: Well that's a different problem. see how this snippet has a video exactly where you want one

Comment: hi i am sorry again, could upload the video tho, it doesn't play...like a photo;(

Comment: Is there a video in the answer? Perhaps your browser ous different to mine. What browser?